# ¿como resuelvo el error que me da de sintaxis en un fichero de un host virtual al intentar arrancar apache2?

Tags: apache2, ssl, certificado-ssl

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio de practica que consiste en crear un host para una pagina  que incluya ssl. el problema lo tengo al configurar el las lineas de ssl en el fichero del host
me ha dejado parar apache pero no me deja arrancarlo esto es el error que me da .

*este seria el systemctl status apache2*

[image: este seria el systemctl status apache2]

*Fichero de configuracion de host*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

he revisado ya el fichero del host pero no encuentro el fallo

he intentado activar el modulo ssl pero me da error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: seria importante que adiciones el fichero, o las partes relevantes del mismo. sino va ser dificil poder ayudarte.

Comment: gracias no me di cuenta que no lo agregue, ya esta adjuntado

Comment: Tienes el modulo SSL activado (`mod_ssl`) en apache?

Comment: por lo que veo en los módulos activos no...

Comment: he intentado activar el modulo ssl pero me da error, he adjuntado el fallo a la publicación

Comment: Muestra los errores y el archivo de configuración _como texto, con formato_. No todos pueden ver las imágenes. Además, no estás colocando _qué error_ estás teniendo...